# Carregar um Listview em um Fragment a partir de um Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

Estou na seguinte situação:

Tenho um TabBar com 2 Fragments (ProdutoFragment e CarrinhoFragment).
Dentro do ProdutoFragment tenho um ListView com um botão de adicionar que que acionado, adiciona um item em um ListView dentro do CarrinhoFragment e altera também 3 TextView diferentes com os somatórios de valores desse mesmo datasource que carrega a lista.

Como faço pra ele recarregar o CarrinhoFragment pra poder alterar meus dados? No momento, ele só carrega se eu sair do TabBar e voltar.
Mesmo usando o notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Coloca o seu código fonte para que eu possa dar uma melhor resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem Libs para esse trabalho porem no momento não me recordo os nomes, outras duas formas são com Intents é Intents filters ou do jeito mais simples que eu vou exemplificar abaixo.

Na classe da CarrinhoFragment crie o metodo notificarMudancaCarrinho();

```
public void notificarMudancaCarrinho(){
    //aqui sua logica para dar o refresh
    //ex:
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Na classe da Activity crie o metodo notificarMudancaCarrinho();

```
public void notificarMudancaCarrinho(){
    carrinhoFragment.notificarMudancaCarrinho();
}
```

No ProdutoFragment onde faz a adição do produto no carrinho basta adicionar a seguinte linha.

```
((SuaActivity) getActivity()).notificarMudancaCarrinho();
```